# How to create an abstract tree, rather than a postfix expression with the shunting yard algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

I managed to find the following pseudo code on Wikipedia that shows how to use the shunting yard algorithm to create a post-fix expression:

```
While there are tokens to be read:
    Read a token.
    If the token is a number, then push it to the output queue.
    If the token is a function token, then push it onto the stack.
    If the token is a function argument separator (e.g., a comma):
    Until the token at the top of the stack is a left parenthesis, pop              operators off the stack onto the output queue. If no left parentheses are encountered, either the separator was misplaced or parentheses were mismatched.
    If the token is an operator, o1, then:
        while there is an operator token o2, at the top of the operator stack and either
    o1 is left-associative and its precedence is less than or equal to that of o2, or
    o1 is right associative, and has precedence less than that of o2,
            pop o2 off the operator stack, onto the output queue;
    at the end of iteration push o1 onto the operator stack.
If the token is a left parenthesis (i.e. "("), then push it onto the stack.
If the token is a right parenthesis (i.e. ")"):
    Until the token at the top of the stack is a left parenthesis, pop operators off the stack onto the output queue.
Pop the left parenthesis from the stack, but not onto the output queue.
If the token at the top of the stack is a function token, pop it onto the output queue.
If the stack runs out without finding a left parenthesis, then there are mismatched parentheses.
When there are no more tokens to read:
    While there are still operator tokens in the stack:
        If the operator token on the top of the stack is a parenthesis, then there are mismatched parentheses.
        Pop the operator onto the output queue.
Exit.
```

how do I modify this algorithm to produce an abstract syntax tree, what should I do rather than pushing operators or operands to an output?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/254074/how-exactly-is-an-abstract-syntax-tree-created?rq=1).

Comment: Thanks, so am I just doing the same thing but pushing operands to an expression stack instead of an output. And joining the two expressions at the top of the stack with an operator when that would be pushed to an output?

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to describe the easiest way to build AST using shunting yard algorithm, but not the most efficient one.
The idea is just to build a postfix string using that algorithm and then build AST from the postfix string, which is extremely easy. Expression, for example: `a * (b + c) + d`

Postfix string for it:

```
a b c + * d +
```

Let's read tokens from postfix string one by one. If the token is a variable, push it to a stack with nodes. If it's an operand, let's pop two highest elements from the stack with nodes, create another node with current operand in it, and make two extracted nodes it's children. Then push new node in node stack.

In the end we will have only one node left in node stack -- the root of the tree. The tree is built.

This algorithm requires reading the string twice, which is an obvious drawback. On the other hand, it's extremely simple.

More efficient algorithm, without building a postfix string, but with building an AST immediately with shunting yard algorithm is described here: [but it's in C++](http://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2009/02/05/evaluating-expressions-part-3-building-the-ast/).